# Excel: Excluding dates from IRR calculation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, irr

I need to implement a dynamic XIRR formula that exclude all the cash flow which related dates are lower than a reference date.

At the moment I have this construction which helps calculating XIRR based on condition and non-adjacent cells.

`XIRR(VSTACK(-INDEX(INPUT!$C:$C,N(IF(1,MODE.MULT(IF(INPUT!$E$2:$E$101=$A$4,ROW(INPUT!$C$2:$C$101)*{1,1}))))),G4),VSTACK(INDEX(INPUT!$B:$B,N(IF(1,MODE.MULT(IF(INPUT!$E$2:$E$101=$A$4,ROW(INPUT!$C$2:$C$101)*{1,1}))))),G$2))`

Comment: So you have a formula, but what's your question? What happens if you use it, what do you expect. Can you share some data along with expected result with that data?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.